# Getting statistics from resultset

Tags: java, collections, resultset

I have a resultset which returns 5 values. I set that data in a POJO, and added that pojo to a list.

```
datapojo = new OutputViewDataPOJO();
datapojo.setTime(resultado.getInt(1));
datapojo.setCommandDesc(resultado.getString(2));
datapojo.setOkError(resultado.getString(3));
datapojo.setResultDesc(resultado.getString(4));
datapojo.setResultCode(resultado.getInt(5));                    
listPojo.add(datapojo);

    [Description:Call connect, TimeStamp:0, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Waiting open complete, TimeStamp:2468, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Reading card, TimeStamp:0, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Waiting read card, TimeStamp:10329, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Reading card, TimeStamp:0, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Waiting read card, TimeStamp:6671, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Reading card, TimeStamp:0, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Waiting read card, TimeStamp:6704, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Reading card, TimeStamp:0, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Waiting read card, TimeStamp:6578, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Reading card, TimeStamp:0, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Waiting read card, TimeStamp:6578, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Reading card, TimeStamp:0, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
    [Description:Waiting read card, TimeStamp:6594, OkError:OK, ResultCode:0, ResultDesc:null.]
```

the top listed data is printed in console, now my question: 
how can I get the sum of TimeStamp for the Description "Waiting read card". I need to do some statistics, in this case is getting the media value of timeStamp for every Description and I don´t know how to do that.
Please, help me!

Comment: make a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) that has all the relevant fields.

Comment: Hi, could you help me about how could I get statistics? I already have the pojo, but how I continue? Do I have to create an object from resultset and then add it to a list, map? Sorry, I`m lost!

Comment: The `ResultSet` should have all selected columns, so you just read them out and store them in one Pojo for each row. What you do with them from there depends on what you want from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store that data in database and then retrieve , you need create a `database` and `table` (f.e. `user`) with these columns

```
name -age -city -car model -house type
```

Then you can store data `( Insert into user(name, age, city, car_model, house_type) values (?,?,?,?,?)`
and retrieve (`Select * from user where city = 'Madrid'`) etc.

You could have a POJO entity as mentioned in one comments :

```
public class User
{
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private String city;
   private String carModel;
   private String houseType;

  //getters , setters
}
```

Create corresponding table in database, and manipulate with data with `Insert`, `Select` queries.

If you don't want to store data in database, you can create a `Map`s for easy filtering.
f.e.

```
 User user = ...; //an instance of User
 Map<String, List<User>> userCityMap = new HashMap<String,List<User>>(); 
 List<User> userWithThatCity = map.get(user.getCity());
 if(userWithThatCity == null)
 {
   userWithThatCity = new ArrayList<User>();
   userCityMap.put(user.getCity(), userWithThatCity);
 }
 userWithThatCity.add(user);
 ...
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: thanks Sergey, I think I´m not clear, sorry. I don´t need to store data en db. I already have data in db, I only need to get that data and make some statistics, but I dont know the best way, if is better save the resultset in list, map or in a pojo like Dragondraikk said. Thanks!

Comment: If you already have data in database, you can fetch filtered data by Select queries, the ResultSet will be saved as a List of  POJO.

Comment: Sergey, could you help me? I will edit the question to show the real code because I´m driving crazy and I know it should be easier than I think...

Comment: Are you retrieving data from Database by some SQL ? if yes you can do something like :  SELECT sum(timestamp_column_name) from YOUR_TABLE where description_column_name = 'Waiting read card'.  Otherwise tell what  ResultSet is it ?

Comment: Actually I need to understand what do you want to do : prepare result set with filtered (sum) data or calculate sum on already prepared resultset ? The query with sum() function is something that calculates data on database side, then you retrieve that result.

Comment: thanks, I explain better: I have the query  "select * from table" for another method, so I thought it´s much better to reuse the resultset retrieved from that method and I decided to save that query results in a pojo and then in a list. In the current method I need to get some statistics, that´s why I want to do some operations over the list object attributes but I think is much more difficult than implement another query, as you suggest.

Comment: yes , I think it will be much more effective if you implement separate queries for that.